# Trigger WSO2 BPEL from a web-form

Tags: html, wso2, bpel, wso2-business-process, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am using wso2 enterprise integrator. I want to know, can we trigger a BPEL from a customised web form? 
If yes, then how to do it? One more thing, how can I assign a task in BPEL using WSO2 developer studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke BPEL from a web form. BPS expose soap web services of the deployed process. You can create your own web app to invoke them. You can get the URL of the available service from the WSDL details section of the process information page as shown below screenshot. [image: Process information page]

What do you mean by assign a task, developer studio is used to develop the BPEL only. You can then deploy them in BPS.